# Launching a C# dialog from an unmanaged C++ mfc active x dll

Tags: c#, c++, activex, unmanaged

I've been told to write a dialog in C# which must be instantiated from an unmanaged c++ dll.  We do this in other places in our code by simply adding a managed c++ class to the C++ project, then calling the C# dll from the managed c++ class.  However I'm finding that doesn't work for me from where I have to do it.  I think because the c++ dll is an MFCActiveX project.  As soon as i set the clr on any file in this project, it will no longer register correctly.  When i attempt to register it, i get three errors, then a message that it registered.  However when i try to use it i get a 0x80040111 "ClassFactory cannot supply requested class" error.
If anyone has any idea what the problem is here i would greatly appreciate it.  I either need to be able to accomplish this (preferred) or prove that it's not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see how a MFCActiveX project would prevent you from creating the C# class in this way.  Unless it simply does not allow for a managed class to be added.

If you can't get the managed C++ class trick to work, another option is to use COM.  It's possible to register a factory of sorts in the C# project as a COM object.  Say give it the following interface

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("babe87fc-1467-4913-a1d3-47eeedf1afb5")]
public interface IDialogFactory {
  void Create(); 
}
```

You'd also have to create a backing class as well.  But then you could register the managed assembly and use COM to access it.

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now using that method.  Very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must now register it with "regasm" instead of "regsvr32".